# How properly distribute load of long-lived http connections in K8s/EKS with ALB + NodePorts (Instance Mode)?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

When using instance mode in EKS with ALB ingresses and scaling up (using HPA), the new pods are not receiving traffic for a long period of time. Instead the existing pods keep taking the traffic.

This is due to both how K8s and iptables routing works: https://learnk8s.io/kubernetes-long-lived-connections and also the fact that the ALB doesn't understand the http requests within the connections, thus isn't able to differentiate and distribute them. I've been unable to find configuration the ALB provides for fixing this distribution of http requests issue.

Are there any options for solving this in K8s, ALBs or EKS?

Comment: I am facing same issue and struggle to find a solution so far. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Any solution for above issue

Answer (score 0):

Trying using IP address for the target type. See https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/annotations/#target-type for details.

Example:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

Do keep in mind that this may cause errors on scale up or scale down. Make sure your AWS ALB health checks are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issues and `target-type: ip` was not an option, because it only works with VPC CNI and we use Calico CNI instead. After some investigation I came up with two possible solutions here: NLB+nginx ingress and `Local` external traffic policy configured for Service.

NLB+nginx option requires more effort to implement and it adds yet another proxy to the request pipeline, that why I ruled it out.

Setting external traffic to `Local` has minor downside, because from ALB perspective nodes with no pod would appear `unhealthy` and only nodes with pods that actually can accept requests would appear as `healthy`. But that's a small price to pay. Remember that pods have to have health checks configured so that ALB knows which nodes it can forward requests to. Also balancing would benefit from `Least Outstanding Request` algorithm, because there clearly will be less connections open to a new pod on a new node. And it's worthwhile to make sure that the new pods are scheduled to the new nodes, otherwise they will unlikely to receive any new traffic.

On Ingress side following annotations are needed:

```yaml
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: <your-health-endpoint>
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: load_balancing.algorithm.type=least_outstanding_requests
```

And on the Service side:

```yaml
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```